# Fetch Parent & Child records Quickbase API_DoQuery

Tags: quickbase

I have a table A and Table B.

A is parent of B

What I want to do is perform a quickbase API call API_DoQuery to get the records in table A with all child records, something like this

id,
name
child:[id, name]

how can I do that right now I only got the values in table A and a number in the relation field
.
What I need to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Erich's answer may help or Two `API_DoQuery` calls per record could achieve this.Please post the code that was tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Combined Text summary field on the parent table to pull all child values into a single comma separated field on the parent table. Since Combined Text fields only work with strings, the Name field should work fine, but for the Record ID you need to first convert that to a string (text) in  a new formula text field on the child table.

Summary field on parent:

[image]

Formula field to convert Record ID from numeric to string:
[image]

Comment: This is a good approach, Seems like OP wants child's ID & Name only so this approach could further be improvised & all needed fields could be fetched in 1 DoQuery call.